Grid Layout not working in Safari, but displays perfect on other browsers(Chrome, Edge, Firefox)
I am struggling to find the solution to make this layout display as a grid with mutiple columns on Safari. It only displays as one column, as the p/images take up the full width of the page. I'm not sure what needs to be tweaked with the code.
Layout is from codepen
Here is the CSS code for the layout:
.grid {
    display: grid;
    margin: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;

    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
}

.feature-letter {
    font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 900;

    font-size: calc(
        100px + (550 - 100) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1000 - 320))
    ); //550px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543871673-fb355dc4e349?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    shape-margin: 0.5rem;
    shape-outside: polygon(
        6.13% 18.73%,
        5.97% 84.82%,
        39.05% 84.64%,
        43.15% 60.82%,
        66.73% 83.73%,
        101.49% 83.64%,
        79.49% 59.81%,
        89.11% 54.91%,
        94.27% 48.09%,
        96.59% 36.55%,
        91.11% 25%,
        74.52% 19.27%
    );
}

.feature-intro {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.052rem;
    font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;  
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;

    &.start {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.4;

        &::first-letter {
            font-size: 28px;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            padding: 0 0 0 5px;
        }
    }
}

.nestedGrid {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
    font-size: 0.65rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.052rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    grid-gap: 1.25rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "text1"
        "text2"
        "text3";

    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "text1 text2"
            "text1 text2"
            "text3 text3";
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "text1 text2 text3"
            "text1 text2 ."
            ". . .";
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.image1 {
    grid-area: image1;
}

.image2 {
    grid-area: image2;
}

.text1 {
    grid-area: text1;
    align-items: start;
}

.text2 {
    grid-area: text2;
}

.text3 {
    grid-area: text3;
}

// Text
h2 {
    margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-style: italic;
    transform: translateX(-0.5rem);
}

p + img,
img + h2 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}



I tried changing the display to flex which added columns in Safari, but messed up the responsive design of the layout. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Works fine in Safari for me (same as on Chrome). (Safari aversion 16.4)

It's fine for me (Safari iPad IOS 16.7.7). What version and what OS and device are you using?

I'm using Safari v15.5 on MacBook Pro.

Safari didn’t implement CSS nesting until 16,5 according to canIuse, so remove the CSS nesting and replace with full selectors.
